# Changing domain of Google App Engine website, but keeping all data

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps

This thing has been keeping me busy for days.

Here's the situation:

I have a website already running on Google App Engine, let's say it is accesible through www.olddomain.com, and users with a google account ending with @olddomain.com have access to the site.

The authentication options are set to Google Apps, and I have a Google Apps account for olddomain.com

No I want to change the website to www.newdomain.com, I want to keep all data and I also want the users to keep their personal data.

I have found a way to change the user accounts from user@olddomain.com to user@newdomain.com

When users aren't logged in to my website, they are redirected to a Google login page, with '@olddomain.com' automatically put after the textbox where they can fill in their account name.

Here is the question:

Is there any way to change the text '@olddomain.com' to '@newdomain.com' on the Google login page, keeping in mind that I want to keep all my data, including all personal data of the users, and that the user accounts change from user@olddomain.com to user@newdomain.com?

Basically, I want to change 'olddomain.nl' to 'newdomain.nl' in the screenshot below:
[image: Screenshot of problem]

Comment: i think setting the new domain as alias for the existing domain would do

Comment: That still asks for an @ olddomain.com account to login, instead of an @ newdomain.com account

Comment: Also, I eventually want to get rid of olddomain.com, so I don't want to keep is as a primary domain or whatsoever

Comment: maybe Google Support Team can help http://support.google.com/a/?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

OK, I've noticed that there is an option added to the Google App Engine where you can actually change the Google Apps Account related to the App Engine application. This wasn't there a few days ago. Unfortunately this can only be done when the datastore doesn't contains any user properties, so datastore entities containing user properties have to be backed up, removed and after the change of domain, they have to be uploaded again.

So changing domain still means some extra datastore operations, but they now are limited to the entities containing user properties and more importantly: the blobstore doesn't have to be migrated anymore. That saves a lot of bandwidth.

The problem with the users migration of data keeps existing, however.

Answer (score 0):

A possible but expensive solution (in terms of datastore operations) would be to create a new app under the newdomain, migrate all your data from the "old" application to the new one, and modify all the emails of the users from user@olddomain.com to user@newdomain.com programmatically.

Comment: I have thought of this and I found a solution to migrate the datastore and the blobstore as well (including references from the datastore pointing to the blobstore), and I've found a way to change the user's email adresses. My only concern is, how do I keep the users' emails, calendars, etc. when I make new accounts with @newdomain.com instead of @olddomain.com?

Comment: Is this information stored in your entities in the datastore of your application?

Comment: No, they are Google accounts. I don't want the users to loose all their e-mail messages etc. when I create a new account for them.

Comment: Then, I would propose to contact the GAE and Google Accounts support teams and explain your situation, since I don't think there is an automatic way to achieve this.